# How do I disable a ListItem?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, listitem

I've got a `DropDownList` in ASP.NET that has a `ListItem` that requires being disabled... but I DON'T mean `Enable="False"`. And I also don't want to disable the entire *DropDownList*, just one specific `ListItem`. What I'm talking about is written in **HTML** as `disabled="disabled"`, like so:

```
<option disabled="disabled" value="-1">Disabled Option</option>
```

Anyone know how to do this in ASP.NET?

Comment: What part of `enabled='false'` isn't what you want?

Comment: @TylerH Seriously? This question is 8 years old. It's long been solved. There's two answers below that explains what was needed :)

Comment: Not sure what the age of the question has to do with my question. Also, the answers below don't explain it at all.

Comment: @TylerH You comment reads sarcastically and troll like. It seems pretty obvious to me, but if you're genuinely seeking a serious answer, then this seems like a prime opportunity to open a question on SO

Comment: I'm sorry if you feel that way, but my question is sincere. Remember that you should assume good faith in interactions here. And no, opening a question on SO is not the appropriate avenue, as I'm asking for you to clarify *your* question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried adding `disabled="disabled"` on the ListItem element?

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="id">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Test" Value="value" disabled="disabled" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Bear in mind that browser compatibility varies: http://www.lattimore.id.au/2005/06/18/disable-options-in-a-select-dropdown-element/

Answer (score 11):

You could try setting the [attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.attributes.aspx) from code behind, that way you can programmatically decide what value to be set.

So in your example you would do something like this:

```
var listItem = DropDownList.Items.FindByText("Your Item Text");
listItem.Attributes["disabled"]="disabled";
```