# DropDownListItems. Can't set any items to be disabled when bound to a datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using the code below to grab a list of items from a database and bind them to a dropdownlist.

I insert separator lines in my itemlist and set

```
seperator.Attributes.Add("disabled", "true");
seperator.Enabled = false;
```

This should make the items non-selectable in the dropdown but it doesn't.

If I loop through my items *after* i've bound them, it does work. Surely I should be able to disable certain items before I bind them to a dropdownlist?

```
DropDownList gvCategory = (DropDownList)GridViewActvities.Rows[0].FindControl("gvCategory");
gvCategory.DataSource = formatCategoriesListItems();
gvCategory.DataBind();

public ListItemCollection formatCategoriesListItems()
{
    OracleConnection sqlConn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);
    sqlConn.Open();
    OracleCommand sqlSelect = new OracleCommand(@"SELECT ID, TASKGROUP, TASKCATEGORY FROM HOTT_GROUPS_CATS ORDER BY 'SORT'", sqlConn);
    sqlSelect.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    OracleDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(sqlSelect);
    DataSet myDataset = new DataSet();
    sqlAdapter.Fill(myDataset);
    sqlConn.Close();

    ListItemCollection listItems = new ListItemCollection();
    //add blank item
    listItems.Add(new ListItem(""));
    string PreviousTaskGroup = "";
    // database items to a list ready to bind to the dropdown
    for (int i = 0; i < myDataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string TaskGroup= myDataset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["TASKGROUP"].ToString();
        string TaskCategory = myDataset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["TASKCATEGORY"].ToString();
        string TaskID= myDataset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ID"].ToString();
        // insert a seperator row based on the taskgroup
        if (TaskGroup != PreviousTaskGroup)
        {
            ListItem seperator = new ListItem("--" + TaskGroup + "--", "");
            seperator.Attributes.Add("disabled", "true");
            seperator.Enabled = false;
            listItems.Add(seperator);
            if (i != myDataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
            {
                PreviousTaskGroup = myDataset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["TASKGROUP"].ToString();
                i--;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            listItems.Add(new ListItem(" " + TaskCategory, TaskID));
            if (i != myDataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
            {
                PreviousTaskGroup = myDataset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["TASKGROUP"].ToString();
            }
        }
    } 
    return listItems;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately for your case, I don't think this is possible to do *before* a bind like that. Here is another question on the subject:
[make drop down list item unselectable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379125/make-drop-down-list-item-unselectable)

**Update:**

I'm editing my answer based on Derrick's answer and your comment about it. Derrick is suggesting that *after* the dropdownlist is bound, then go through and disable the separators. So it would look something more like this:

```
protected void gvCategory_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem li in gvCategory.Items)
    {
        if(li.Text.Contains("--"))
            li.Attributes.Add("disabled", "true");
    }
}
```

**Update 2:**

Add the OnDataBound event to manipulate the DropDownList after it is bound.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="gvCategory" runat="server" OnDataBound="gvCategory_DataBound"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to be able to insert the seperator lines into the current dropdownlist's item collection as the datasource does not contain these seperators initially.

Comment: Yes, and you would still do that. Add the separators initially but edit the list of items in the DropDownList after it is bound. See my second update.

Answer (score 0):

The markup should be generated using:

```
seperator.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
```

[ASP.Net: How do I disable a ListItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022292/asp-net-how-do-i-disable-a-listitem)

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't disable the items

Answer (score 0):

Just have FormatCategoriesListItems return the data raw.

Handle gvCategory.Databind() yourself:

```
        protected void gvCategory_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet myDataset = gvCategory.DataSource as DataSet;
        if (myDataset != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < myDataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string TaskGroup = myDataset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["TASKGROUP"].ToString();
                string TaskCategory = myDataset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["TASKCATEGORY"].ToString();
                string TaskID = myDataset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ID"].ToString();
                // insert a seperator row based on the taskgroup
                if (TaskGroup != PreviousTaskGroup)
                {

                    ListItem seperator = new ListItem("--" + TaskGroup + "--", "");
                    seperator.Attributes.Add("disabled", "true");
                    seperator.Enabled = false;
                    listItems.Add(seperator);
                    if (i != myDataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
                    {
                        PreviousTaskGroup = myDataset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["TASKGROUP"].ToString();
                        i--;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    listItems.Add(new ListItem(" " + TaskCategory, TaskID));
                    if (i != myDataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
                    {
                        PreviousTaskGroup = myDataset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["TASKGROUP"].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Looks good but I can't see where you are setting the new datasource for the dropdownlist

Comment: @totalitarian - your code but with formatCategoriesListItems() returning just the data.